# What is this application from the Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

When looking to update apps, i noticed this application is claiming to be installed on my device.

[image: image 1: play store installed apps list]

[image: image 2: application page]

What is this application? I did not ever install it myself, and i have not authorized its update yet. Is this a glitch on Samsung's part? It looks like their memo application but i cannot be sure. Is it a virus intended to fool me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a similar thread [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjA7vrxhNnNAhXGvY8KHXXoDdwQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.androidcentral.com%2Fsamsung-galaxy-s6%2F693236-memo-update-korean.html&usg=AFQjCNFAJO2hAyUA09kNGyFaiL_zMB6_eQ&sig2=ER2XKufQZj-3_hBEM1AQCA), so you aren't entirely alone. Just disable that app for now since it's bloatware anyway!

*(Switched comment to an answer as per comments)*

Comment: In case the link dies, the app is called memo and is standard Samsung bloatware. The play store is probably automatically updated incorrectly, but updating the app shouldn't cause problems.